# Is there a way to have class names be different from your table names?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

We are using a database created several years ago, and would like to keep the table names the same.

All of our tables are named like: "tbl_Orders" but we would like the class names for the models / controllers / etc. to be Orders / OrdersController / etc.  We are mapping the classes to our tables using Entity Framework.

Sorry if this has been asked before, I tried searching but came up empty handed...

**Solution:**

After some back and forth with Scott Chamberlain, we came to the conclusion that both answers are correct.  I went ahead and marked Masoud's answer as accepted, because that is the route I went.  Thank's to everyone who helped (especially Scott).

Comment: asp.net-web-api doesn't specifically have anything to do with your table names. Are you using Entity Framework to map your classes to you tables?

Comment: @hometoast Yes, apologies.  I should have mentioned that / tagged the question with Entity Framework.  I will edit it for clarity now.

Comment: It is possible but you need to provide more details of which way you are creating your models. Did you do DatabaseFirst (the designer view) or CodeFirst (classes you built yourself)? The way you change the class names is totally different for the two methods.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thank you for your response.  I am pretty new at this (as you probably guessed).  We(my predecessors) created the database before EF existed.  The classes haven't been created yet.  I believe we can just generate them by building a model based on the database.  In that case it would be DB first right?

Comment: You can, but there is two ways to do that. One where you generate .cs files directly (code first based on a existing database) and one where you work a .edmx (database first) file that generates the classes int the .designer.cs file. Watch [this video](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj590134), which of the two "Existing database" options are you doing?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thanks for the video, I would be using a Code first workflow.  I watched another video further explaining code first workflow [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620) where it mentions further configuration in the DbContext's OnModelCreating function.  Would the answer provided by Masoud work for me?

Comment: @Primalpat yes, or you can use annotations to configure it like ErikEJ's answer. Both perform the exact same configuration to EF, it is just two ways to perform it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use following code in your `DbContext` to map all your entities to your tables:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   // TableNameConvention
     modelBuilder.Types()
                 .Configure(entity => 
                            entity.ToTable("tbl_" + entity.ClrType.Name));

     base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Answer (score 24):

You can use the Table attribute or the fluent api to map between table names in your database and class names

```
[Table("tbl_Blogs")] 
public class Blog
```

### 3rd party edit

Entity framework core offers the same option to map tablenames or columns

- [map tables names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-types?tabs=data-annotations#table-name)
- [map column names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=data-annotations%2Cwithout-nrt#column-names)

The mapping can be done by using attributes

```
[Table("blogs")]
public class Blog
{        
    [Column("blog_id")]
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

or by using the fluent api

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
        .ToTable("blogs");
    modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
        .Property(b => b.BlogId)
        .HasColumnName("blog_id");
}
```

Comment: Note, that is only if he did CodeFirst, if he did DatabaseFirst getting it to work in the designer is very different.

Comment: So after generating the classes, I can modify their names and add the table attribute?  How would this affect the designer that Scott mentions?

Answer (score 1):

Working on EF Core 7.0(5.0+) and this one worked for me.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   foreach (var mutableEntityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
   {
        // check if current entity type is child of BaseModel
        if (mutableEntityType.ClrType.IsAssignableTo(typeof(BaseEntity)))
        {         
            mutableEntityType.SetTableName($"tbl_{mutableEntityType.ClrType.Name.Pluralize()}");
        }
    }
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```