# How to have different class names and different table names in asp.net mvc + Database First Approach

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on a project using APS.NET MVC with Entity Framework. This application is developed to be integrated with an existing database. In that database, table names are defined as `trip_tab` , `vehicletype_tab`,`driver_tab` & etc.

I want to create my model class names like `Trip`,`VehicleType`,`Driver`. and also controllers should be `TripController`,`VehicleTypeController` & etc.

There is a most similar question in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26219848/is-there-a-way-to-have-class-names-be-different-from-your-table-names). But it is not the solution for my problem because it has a concatenated prefix to the class name.

How to do this in my case?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The second answer to your linked question should do exactly what you're looking for. Have you tried it?

Comment: @Stephen Although the question was duplicated, my case was different. And also the solution is not same. Solution 1 is not working for me. and also the 2nd answer is also not working. 
The solution is refactoring the table names in .edmx file. after changing them, the `[Table("mytablename")]` attribute will be deleted automatically. The solution that worked for me was not in that question.

Comment: Then I will remove the dupe so that you can add your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just refactor the entity name in the Entity Framework Model (.edmx file) then the Model classes will be renamed automatically. After changing the model class names we can create controllers according to that model class names.

see following screen shots.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74zvZ.png) is how my table names are.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYfoz.png) is how i changed my entity names in .edmx file.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for the same problem.. 
and i found annotation helpful

use

```
[Required]
[Column("FirstName")]
[Display(Name = "First Name")]
[StringLength(50)]
public string FirstMidName { get; set; }
```

this way you can handle the things with properties